# NumPy: sort ndarray 1st axis by selected 2nd axis element

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization

I have an array n x m x k. The task is to sort 1st axis by selected 2nd axis element. Currently i do it like in example below. The input array is 3x3x3, axis 1 is sorted by 1st element of 2nd axis. Is there more efficient way using nditer?

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.random.rand(27).reshape(3,3,3)
print(a)

for i in np.arange(np.shape(a)[0]):
    idx = np.argsort(a[i,:,1])
    a[i]=a[i,idx]

print(a)
```

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I wanted. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Get the `argsort` indices selecting all elements along the first axis in one-go and then use NumPy's [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to index along the second axis to get the re-arranged output -

```
idx = np.argsort(a[:,:,1])
a_out = a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
```

**Approach #2**

If we are doing in-situ edits in the input array (writing back the results to input), we can run a loop after pre-computing those `argsort` indices, like so -

```
idx = np.argsort(a[:,:,1])
for i,indx in enumerate(idx):
    a[i] = a[i,indx]
```

#### Benchmarking

```
# Original method
In [130]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.rand(100,100,100)

In [131]: %%timeit
     ...: for i in np.arange(np.shape(a)[0]):
     ...:     idx = np.argsort(a[i,:,1])
     ...:     a[i]=a[i,idx]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop

# Approach #1
In [132]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.rand(100,100,100)

In [133]: %%timeit
     ...: idx = np.argsort(a[:,:,1])
     ...: a_out = a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 ms per loop

# Approach #2
In [134]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.rand(100,100,100)

In [135]: %%timeit
     ...: idx = np.argsort(a[:,:,1])
     ...: for i,indx in enumerate(idx):
     ...:     a[i] = a[i,indx]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 ms per loop
```